# Saving Permalinks Results in 403 MAMP (Windows)

Tags: theme-development, server, localhost, local-installation, windows

I am trying to setup a local environment on my Windows 10 machine (to knock out some overtime) but keep running into a problem. Let me start with my environment workflow on Mac OSX... I have developed many sites locally over the years using MAMP Pro, allowing me to have a host for each project. However, at home I have just recently switched to the Windows environment. I downloaded MAMP Pro for Windows (which is identical at least in UI) and setup everything. I worked for a bit just fine, but didn't notice until now, that if you try to go to any other page but the home page, I get a 403 Forbidden Error. I can even kick start this error by saving permalinks (renders the entire host/site as a 403, nothing works.)

The only way I can get the site to appear again is to remove everything from the `.htaccess` file. Then I have the homepage again (admin works fine) but thats it. When I save permalinks this is what it produces in the `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I feel like my question might be kind of broad, but what could the issue be here? Is it permissions? I feel pretty well versed in in servers/unix/permissions but throwing Windows into the picture gets me hung up. I'm also using Cmder for a command line tool.

Comment: this sounds like mod_rewrite is not enabled, although not sure why would you get a 403 in that case but maybe it is a mamp thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not *really* a an answer when it comes to MAMP's problem on Windows. Installing WAMP and running WordPress there instead fixed this issue.

Answer (score -2):

You have to add **your project directory name** into **RewriteBase** and **RewriteRule**.

For Example:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is the case. It lives in the project lives in the root directory, being `/` since its a virtual host.